# Assigning role to Group in GCP causing Role does not exist in the resource's hierarchy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am trying to assign below role to group in Gcp

Role : - Service Consumer

role id: - roles/servicemanagement.serviceConsumer

Command:-
`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding Project_id --member=group:group1 --role=roles/servicemanagement.serviceConsumer`

Error : -

**ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.**

**ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role (roles/servicemanagement.serviceConsumer) does not exist in the resource's hierarchy.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the the service management roles are only applicable to Cloud Endpoints services:

```sh
gcloud endpoints services add-iam-policy-binding ${SERVICE} \
--member:group:${GROUP_EMAIL} \
--role=roles/servicemanagement.serviceConsumer
```

See: https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/access-control#managing_access_using_cloud_sdk

> **NOTE** (Google) Groups values should be an email address of the form `name@somewhere.com`.